# Powershell to change "Allow members to invite others to site members group"

Tags: powershell, 2016, access

In the Access Request settings of a site, you have the top two check boxes that pertain to Members share permissions. I found a script elsewhere that changes the "Allow members to share the site" checkbox, but I cannot find one that changes the "Allow members to invite others to site members group". There is a Set-SPOSite, but this is an on-prem 2016 farm so that command doesn't work.

I need a powershell script because there are about 500 site collections that need to have this changed.

Comment: Have you given set-sposite a try?  Most (though not all) spo and pnp cmdlets work for 2013 and higher on-prem too.

Comment: I did give it a try and it wasnt recognized as a cmdlet.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone else. To disable only the second check box, if you use the PnP Powershell module:

```
 # Connect to the site:
 Connect-PnPOnline -Url $InsertSiteURLHere -Interactive

 $web = Get-PnPWeb
 $ctx = Get-PnPContext

 $ctx.Load($web.AllProperties)
 $web.AssociatedMemberGroup.AllowMembersEditMembership = $False
 $web.AssociatedMemberGroup.Update()
 $web.Update()

 $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

 Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Adapted from this Source: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/10/sharepoint-online-access-request-email-settings-powershell.html